# How do I remove a threaded drywall toggle?

Tags: drywall-anchor

This is the threaded drywall anchor I am using:

[image]

It is currently stuck in my ceiling in this same exact posture.    I have taken the screw and hook at the bottom out, however the anchor is now stuck tight and I was hoping to find a way to take it out aside from snipping the top off with bolt cutters and pushing it in or excavating the ceiling drywall to take it all out (then having to go through patching the giant hole)

Comment: use a toothpick to move the toggle out of the way

Comment: Patching a tiny hole or carefully cutting a hole just big enough not much difference.  Being careful no electric wires or gas/water pipes are cut.  Using a sledge to make the hole is a different matter.